# В чем смысл конструкции Bar.prototype = new Foo()

Tags: javascript, prototype

Объясните пожалуйста, почему происиходит вызов функции?

```js
Foo = function() {
    document.write("Hello");
}

var Bar = function() {
    Foo.call(this);
}

Bar.prototype = new Foo();
```

Правильно ли я вообще понимаю этот код?
Я рассуждаю так:
1)Обычная функция `foo()` просто выводит `"Hello"`
2)В теле функции `Bar()` вызывается `Foo()` в контексте объекта `Bar.prototype`? Делаю подобный вывод, в виду того, что `this`  в случае вызова функции `Foo()` с `new` должно указывать на тот объект, который является левым операндом операции присваивания (топорно, но это из наблюдений и матчасти)! 
3)Ну и последнее, не понятное для меня явление. `Bar.prototype` это же ссылка на объект, который будет являться прототипом для объектов, созданных с помощью функции `Bar()`? То-есть, мы присваиваем объекту `Bar.prototype` новый сконструированный с помощью `new` объект, в теле которого единственная инструкция `document.write()`, вообще впервые вижу, чтобы объектах кроме свойств и "методов" были какие-либо исполняющие конструкции?
Ответьте пожалуйста на мой вопрос, правильно ли я вообще рассуждаю, хотя судя по тому, что я не понимаю, видать где-то пробел! В общем жду ответов опытных в этом вопрос програмистов, спасибо за внимание! p.s.: просьба не задавать мне вопросы, вроде "ну а ты сам как думаешь (прицендент между прочим)". Если бы я всё понимал, я бы не отнимал у вас время , уважаемые! Спасибо!

Comment: Могу вам дать совет. Найдите нормальный пример реализации прототипного наследования и тогда вопросы отпадут. Потому что на примере, который не делает ничего вразумительного, сложно дать вразумительный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример у вас и правда странный, но давайте разберемся

```
Foo = function() {
    document.write("Hello");
}

Foo(); // Просто вызов функции
new Foo(); // Вернет нам экземпляр Foo, сейчас это пустой объект
```

Да, `Foo` сейчас просто функция, однако ее все еще можно вызвать с `new`, просто она вернет экземпляр `Foo`, в данном случае это просто пустой объект

Идем дальше:

```
var Bar = function() {
    Foo.call(this);
}
```

Опять же, вы верно сказали, что это просто вызов функции `Foo` в контексте `this`, но есть ньюанс, этот контекст **не всегда равен** экземпляру `Bar`, все зависит от того, как именно вызывается `Bar`

```
const Foo = function () {
  console.log(this);
  console.info('Invoke!');
}

const Bar = function() {
    Foo.call(this);
}

Bar(); // контекст глобальный и может быть как `window`, так и что-то другое
new Bar(); // контекст экземпляр Bar
```

Последняя строка:

```
Bar.prototype = new Foo();
```

Перезаписали прототип, сейчас это снова пустой объект, если бы там были какие-то методы/св-ва, то они были бы доступны в экземплярах `Bar`

**Заключение**: 
Пример и правда странный, лучше поискать более практичные примеры или переходить на классы, которые доступны в `js`. Это все те же прототипы, но выглядит все более семантично, что ли https://learn.javascript.ru/es-class

Comment: во первых благодарю за старания! Но печально то, что я так и не понял, за счёт чего вызвалась функция `Foo()`, почему в рабочую область документа вывелся "Hello"!? Что вообще означает создание объекта объекта, которому передаются исполняющие команды вроде doc.write()? Ведь если просто создать объект с помощью описания литерала, и добавить туда doc.write() ничего не появится в рабочей области! Короче у меня каша в голове, я не понимаю данного синтаксиса, хотя и вроде понял всё , что вы написали

Comment: сейчас ради интереса в кодепене сделал `function foo(){
  document.write("Gizza is an object")
}` и потом `new foo()` ума не приложу, как получилось, что в документе отобразилась эта фраза, ведь я всего-навсего просто создал пустой объект командой `new foo()` на основе функции `foo()`

Comment: @Muranx смотрите, функция **выполняется**, а потом возвращает объект, то есть код внутри функции выполнится при любом вызове, не важно с `new` или без него, отличается то, что вернется после вызова

Comment: хм, окей, уже что-то! Ну а теперь точка `"G"`, смотрите. . . Ведь `Bar.prototype` это же объект прототип для всех экземпляров , которые будут созданы с помощью `Bar()` ведь так? И что мы делаем? Присваиваем этому объекту новый объект с помощью конструктора `foo()`(чую не зря вы мне сказали про не совсем умный код)? И по поводу `this`, получается в последней операции `this` будет указывать на тот объект, который создаётся в результате `bar.prototype=foo()`? Это по Кайлу Симпсону (You dont know JS) серия книг

Comment: `new Bar()` вызовет `Foo` в контексте экземпляра `Bar`, у которого в прототипе будет экземпляр `Foo`, но на выходе мы все так же получим экземпляр именно `Bar`